# AOP doesn't work when class implements interface

Tags: spring, spring-aop, spring-bean

I'm new with aspects and this is my second question about it. I have an Aspect running over 3 classes: A which is abstract and B and C which both inherit from A. Now, when I have A implementing the interface Testable, Spring doesn't load my contexts. It throws a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:

```
No matching bean of type [com.test.test.impl.A] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
```

Nonetheless, if I comment the advice, it works.

***Interface Testable***:

```
package com.test.test;

public interface Testable {

    public void doStuff();
}
```

***Test***

```
public class AppTest  {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("a1")
    private  A a1;
    @Autowired
    private  A a2;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("b")
    private  B b;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("c")
    private  C c;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        a1.doStuff();
        a2.doStuff();
        a1.doMoreStuff();
        a2.doMoreStuff();
        b.doStuff();
        b.doMoreStuff();
        c.doStuff();
        c.doMoreStuff();
    }
}
```

***Class A***:

```
package com.test.test.impl;

import com.test.test.Testable;

public abstract class A implements Testable{
    public abstract void doMoreStuff();

    public void doStuff(){
        System.err.println("Inside A.doStuff()");
    }
}
```

***Class B***

```
package com.test.test.impl;

public class B extends A{
    @Override
    public void doMoreStuff() {
        System.err.println("Inside B.doMoreStuff()");
   }
}
```

***Class C***

```
package com.test.test.impl;

public class C extends A{
    @Override
    public void doMoreStuff() {
        System.err.println("Inside C.doMoreStuff()");
   }
}
```

***Aspect***

```
package com.test.test.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Around("execution(* com.test.test..*.*(..))")
    public Object miAspecto(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable{
        System.err.println("");
        System.err.println("Before the method runs");
        System.err.println("Invoking " + joinPoint.getSignature());
        Object o = joinPoint.proceed();
        System.err.println("After the method runs");
        System.err.println("Result " + o);
        System.err.println("");
        return o;
    }
}
```

What's the problem with it?

Thanks in advance.

PS: Why some times all the lines in the aspect get printed before the one in the method itself?

Comment: `System.err` is async it prints when it think it needs to print there is no guarantee in ordering. Use `System.out` instead (or better a logging framework). AOP is working perfectly your injection isn't because you should be programming to interfaces instead of concrete classes (that is the whole point of interfaces). Spring uses proxy based AOP and at run time it creates a dynamic proxy (due to the interface) which implements the interfaces but doesn't extend a class. So there are multiple instances of `Testable` and no instances of `A`, `B` and `C` those are hidden in a proxy.

Comment: But I already tried using Testable instead of classes or abstract classes commenting the method added and it didn't work either... You say by just changing the auto wired declarations it works?

Comment: Yes. I you use the interface instead of concrete classes injection works, however you won't be able to call `doMoreStuff ` as that isn't part of the interface.

Comment: you were right, i don't know what I did before. Anyway, I though the way the proxy worked was inheriting the class, not implementing the interface :/

Comment: what if somwhere in the code i wanna call doMoreStuff? can't I because of the aspect?

Comment: No because of the interface. The whole point of using interfaces is that you don't need nor should know the implementation. If you need an additional method you will need it in the interface.

Answer (score 1):

To make this work you need to add `proxyTargetClass=true` in aop config like `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)` for java based configuration or `<aop:config proxy-target-class="true"></aop:config>` for xml based configuration. This way spring aop will add the proxies forcefully.